# Python: Pandas - Nested Loop takes very long to complete. How to speed up?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I am self learning Python and Pandas to support my daily job. With a lot of trial and error, I have built the below function. This function takes as arguments (i) a dataframe referenced as 'dataset', (ii) a list of country names and (iii) a list of unique legal entity IDs. (The function works.)

The dataset is a large dataframe with 300,000+ rows and approximately 30 columns -- it is a dump of a general ledger. The key columns are "LE_ID" and "COUNTRY", that respectively contain (i) an unique ID for the relevant legal entity and (ii) the name of the country of that legal entity. Not all rows are unique, there's approx 5000 LE_IDs filling the 300,000+ rows.

I want to "split" this dataset into XLS files that, per country, outline, per tab, the ledger details of every LE_ID. The below function achieves this. But at a horrible speed -- it takes 40 mins to complete on my pretty recent laptop.

The function:

```
def SplitDatasetByCountry(dataset, countries, ids):
        
    for country in countries:

        ## output
        output_folder = Path('/Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TOOL/Reports')
        output_filename = 'Data__for_' + str(country) + '_.xlsx'
        output = output_folder / output_filename
    
        ## writer
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output)
        workbook = writer.book

        ## country logic
        x = dataset.loc[dataset['COUNTRY'] == country]
        
        ids_for_entities_in_country = x['LE_ID'].to_list()
        unique_ids = list(set(ids_for_entities_in_country))

        for id in ids:

            if id in unique_ids:
                y = x.loc[x['LE_ID'] == id]
                y.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(id))
                
            else:
                pass
        
        writer.save()
        workbook.close()
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions how to speed this up. I think I am excessively iterating, which is causing the issue, but I am not sure how to solve this. Yesterday's version of this function was a bit faster, but I ended up w/ corrupted XLS files -- probably because I accidently had the code writer over the same xls file multiple times.

I understand from the community here that list comprehensions are preferred, but I can't figure out the right syntax to get my function organized. I would prefer to keep iterating, but eliminating the current (seemingly?) redundant iterations.

thanks for your thoughts

First UPDATE MAY 28:

The dataset has the following fields

```
LE_ID               object
LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME   object
COUNTRY             object
GL_ACCOUNT                              object
BOOK_AMT                                int64
ADJUSTED_TAX                            float64
```

Second UPDATE MAY 28:

Revised code per suggestion in comments, works flawlessly:

```
def SplitDatasetByCountry(dataset):

for country, country_df in dataset.groupby('COUNTRY'):
      
    ## output
    output_folder = Path('/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Reports')
    output_filename = 'Data_for_' + str(country) + '_.xlsx'
    output = output_folder / output_filename

    ## writer
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output)
    workbook = writer.book
    
    ## country logic            
    country_expenses = function_A(country_df)
    country_income = function_B(country_df)
    expense = country_expenses.groupby('LE_ID')['BOOK_AMT'].sum()
    income = country_income..groupby('LE_ID')['BOOK_AMT'].sum()
    expense.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Country Expense')
    income.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Country Income')
    
    for le_id, le_id_df in country_df.groupby('LE_ID'):
        le_id_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(le_id))
                    
    writer.save()
    workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the format of the dataframe before it enters your function ?

If that format is good enough then simply splitting the dataframe according to the country, then the ids should be enough :

```
list_of_dfs = [dataset[["COUNTRY"] == country] for country in dataset["COUNTRY"].unique()]
```

I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish with the id, but i can at least point out that you can get uniques directly as above using `.unique()` on a `Series`, cf [pandas' doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) :

```
unique_ids = dataset["LE_ID"].unique()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the .unique() method -- that is really helpful. I have updated my post above with the key fields of the dataset. Can you have a look -- I believe perhaps the format is "not good enough" -- as you wrote -- for the list comprehension you provided resulted in a Key Error (key). Is it correct that w/ the list comprehension you kindly suggested, the item "== country'' references any value in the column "COUNTRY" i.e. is not a reference to another variable?

Answer (score 0):

There is two terms that need to be understand.

Vectorization and traditional loops.

If you use for loops even nested for loops. The time complexity will increase
in the order of O(n^2).

But if you use Vectorization, your algorithm is likely to work faster.

Instead of for loops, try to do the problem using numpy summations or dot functions and it will be more faster.

[This the example for implementing vectorization techniques](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l9RA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by COUNTRY first, then group by LED_ID and write the result to file.

```
for country, country_df in dataset.groupby('COUNTRY'):
    ## output
    output_folder = Path('/Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TOOL/Reports')
    output_filename = 'Data__for_' + str(country) + '_.xlsx'
    output = output_folder / output_filename
    ## writer
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output) as writer:
        for led_id, led_df in country_df.groupby("LED_ID"):
            led_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(led_id))
```

Comment: Thanks you Alexander for your suggestion, which works flawlessly. Whereas my original version required more than 40 minutes to complete (no doubt due to redunant iterations), your version completes in a few minutes. I need to study the groupby method further as I don't quite understand what's happening. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Uploaded the revised code in the original post above for future reference. Note the additional functions A and B that work some separate magic on the dataframe, and get printed to their own sheets as well.